# Extract text string from URL using regex

Tags: regex

Basically, I have list of URLs that look like this:

```
http://auctionnetwork.com.my/auctiondate_img.php?id=244003
```

and I want to extract `auctiondate_244003`, how would I do that with regex?

I want the output to be "auctiondate_244003".

Comment: Which lang  you're running? Post your attempts.

Comment: I just want the regex code

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define exactly what you are looking for.
How about something like: `\/([^\/]*)img\.php\?id=([0-9]+)`?
You'll have to concatenate the 1st and second match groups to get what you need

See https://regex101.com/r/dD2hW6/1

Comment: Thanks Uri. but your code outputs "/auctiondate_img.php?id=244003". I wanted the output "auctiondate_244003"

Comment: If you look at the two match group you get - `auctiondate_` and `244003` and concatenate them, you'll get exactly what you want.